# How can I prove /disprove my observation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $k$ be a divisor of $n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1$ , then either $k$ or $k-1$ is divisible by $5$.

I solved this problem by considering the prime factorization of $k$ and showing it to be either $5$ or $1$ modulo $5$ with the help of Fermat's Little Theorem and an elementary divisibility trick.

I noticed that there was nothing special about number $5$ here, by similar reasoning one can show that any divisor of $n^{p-1}+n^{p-2}+...+n+1$ is either divisible by $p$ or $1$ mod $p$.

While proving this, I made this observation ;

> Let $f(n,k)=a_nn^k+a_{n-1}n^{k-1}+...a_0$  ( $\forall a_k$ integers),
>   then
>
> $f(m,k)$ is always divisible by $\gcd[(n-m), f(n,k)]$

I checked this for random numbers, and it turned out to be true. I have been trying to prove it with the same techniques but for some reason, these are not working.

How can I approach this conjecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $$f(n,k)-f(m,k)=a_k(n^k-m^k)+\cdots+a_1(n-m)$$ is divisible by $n-m$. So
$$f(m,k)=f(n,k)+(n-m)A,$$
and your statement follows.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\ldots+1=\Phi_p(x)=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$$
is a [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). Assuming that $q\neq p$ is a prime divisor of $\Phi_p(x)$, from:
$$ \Phi_p(x)\equiv 0\pmod{q} $$
it follows that the order of $x$ in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/_{q\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*\simeq\mathbb{F}_q^*$ is $p$. Lagrange's theorem hence gives $p\mid(q-1)$, or:
$$ q\equiv1\pmod{p}, $$
so any divisor of $\Phi_p(x)$ is either congruent to $0$ or to $1 \pmod{p}$ as conjectured.